# $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] path not working in HTML href

Tags: php

I tried couple of ways to echo out an absolute path in href attribute but didn't work. Here is a brief introduction of what I am talking about.

I have sliced head tag into a head.php file. I have to use that same head file in other pages. Due to the document root level, I am not getting short-icon as I used relative path. So I decided to use absolute path in object oriented way.

```
class Config {

    public static $url = null;
    public static $ext = null;

    public function __construct()
    {
        self::$url = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
        self::$ext = '/bcc-wd-batch1/imran17507/php/ecommerce/';
    }
}
```

Then in the `head.php`:

```
<?php 
    include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/bcc-wd-batch1/imran17507/php/ecommerce/vendor/autoload.php');
    use Site\Utility\Config;

    $config = new Config();

    $url = "file:///".Config::$url.Config::$ext;

    //Tried $url = Config::$url.Config::$ext; too
    //echo $url;

    ?>

<--This is where I wan't to make the changes.-->

    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="../../../medias/favicon/apple-touch-icon.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="../../../medias/favicon/favicon-32x32.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="../../../medias/favicon/favicon-16x16.png">
    <link rel="manifest" href="../../../medias/favicon/site.webmanifest">
    <link rel="mask-icon" href="../../../medias/favicon/safari-pinned-tab.svg" color="#5bbad5">
```

And the variations that I tried in the link tags:

**1.**

```
<?php
echo '<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="'.$url.'medias/favicon/apple-touch-icon.png">';
echo '<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="'.$url.'medias/favicon/favicon-32x32.png">';
echo '<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="'.$url.'medias/favicon/favicon-16x16.png">';
echo '<link rel="manifest" href="'.$url.'medias/favicon/site.webmanifest">';
echo '<link rel="mask-icon" href="'.$url.'medias/favicon/safari-pinned-tab.svg" color="#5bbad5">';
echo '<meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#da532c">';
echo '<meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">';
?>
```

**2.**

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="<?=$url;?>medias/favicon/apple-touch-icon.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="<?=$url;?>medias/favicon/favicon-32x32.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="<?=$url;?>medias/favicon/favicon-16x16.png">
<link rel="manifest" href="<?=$url;?>medias/favicon/site.webmanifest">
<link rel="mask-icon" href="<?=$url;?>medias/favicon/safari-pinned-tab.svg" color="#5bbad5">
```

Now I am officially out of ways.

Comment: What is your question? Is anything not working with the generated code?

Comment: Are you launching this script from a brower or through command line ?

Comment: Absolute path to the browser is different from the document root, which is a place on the file system. You should never expose this to the browser - the medias folder needs to be available via the web server. You might want an Apache `Alias` to do this, or it might already be available depending on your folder structure. It looks like your href should be `"/bcc-wd-batch1/medias/..."`

Comment: I tried to link short-icon for my website using absolute path. But I just can't figure out how to use absolute path in href attribute. But if I use relative path, I can see the short-icon meaning it works fine. Either href attribute doesn't support absolute path or I don't know!

Yes I am launching this script from a browser(localhost)

Comment: @cmbuckley Exactly that's the answer

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this will help resolve your situation but inside the head you can set the `base` tag which means everything will be referenced relative from there:

```
<head>
    <title></title>
    <base href="https://www.example.com/">
    <link.....>
    <script.....>
</head>
```

Answer (score 1):

So, I wanted to use absolute path in href attribute. What I didn't know was, Absolute path in PHP and Absolute Path in html are different.

**Absolute path in PHP**

```
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
```

**But absolute path in HTML is:**

```
href="/pages/index.php"
```

**Literally, A forward slash(/) was the answer to my question and hours of trying variations and looking for answers**

Again, Absolute Path in html is just a forward slash

Comment: Absolute path in URLs is the same as with (Unix) file paths: the leading slash indicates that the path starts at the root.